# Reassigning the primary search key to another key within my item, is this possible? (DynamoDB)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

My items in my dynamodb database look like this...

{'symbol': 'MSFT', 'date': '2019-02-01 16:00:00', 'open': 102.63, 'high': 102.81, 'low': 102.62, 'close': 102.8, 'volume': 673176.0}

I accidentally made the primary search key 'symbol' and my secondary search key 'date'. I would like to switch date to be my primary search key.

What is the best course of action to get to this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table definition is such that `symbol` is the hash key and `date` the range key, you are going to have to delete the table and recreate it with the hash and range keys changed.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance Brian! I'll do just that. If you could upvote my post to help me to get to 15 rep I would love to select your answer and upvote it too!